# Recorrer un ArrayList y mostrar uno por uno

Tags: android, loops, timer

Estoy usando un `for` para recorrer una lista de objetos, pero solo me muestra el ultimo, en consola si me muestra que recorre todos, pero en el `Imageview` solo muestra el ultimo.

Codigo:

```
if(!L.isEmpty()){
      for (Bits bits : L){
         imageBit.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(bits.getbImage()));
         nameBit.setText(bits.getbText());
       }
   }
```

pero necesito mostrar uno por uno en el `imageview`, por ejemplo Muestra el primero, luego el segundo, y así hasta terminar, no se si se ocupe un `TIMER` o como poder hace?

Answer (score 2):

Tu puedes cambiar el contenido de un `ImageView` usando:

```
ImageView iView;
// instar iView segun layout
iView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Así si obtienes tus `Drawable` desde un ArrayList, puedes actualizar el contenido del `ImageView` uno por uno.

En vez de un `Timer`, usa un `Handler` con un `Runnable` para actualizar el imagen. Eso te garantiza que la actualisación esta hecho desde la hebra UI.

```
// en tu activity
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
// y tienes por ejemplo un ArrayList con los Drawable
ArrayList<Drawable> imagenes;

public class Actualizador implements Runnable{
    int i=0;
    @Override
    public void run(){
        if (i<imagenes.size()){
            iView.setImageDrawable(imagenes.get(i++));
            mHandler.postDelayed(this,3000); // reejecutar despues de 3000 ms
        }
    }
}

mHandler.post(new Actualizador());
```

Ahora, si quieres construir el imagen como bitmap desde un arreglo de Bits, tu código hace exactamente lo que tu le pides: iterar sobre el arreglo y poner los bits actuales en el imagen. Si quieres construir un imagen que como resulto final tiene **todos** los bits como contenido, tienes que concatenar los Bits en vez de remplazarlos. En este caso tienes que elaborar un poco más como pretendes de construir tu imagen desde los componentes.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda! me ayudo en entender el como manejar imagenes estaticas en el drawable para recorrerlas.

Answer (score 0):

Al usar un Imageview solo puedes ingresar un único valor. No puedes mostrar 10 imágenes en 1 solo imageView. Intenta usar un Listview y así podrás verlas todas.

Comment: Si quisiera ver una por una, y no una lista de todos los objetos, osea ver el primero y que se quite y luego ver el segundo, hasta llegar al ultimo, como lo podria hacer? con un RecyclerView o con la ListView puedo ir mostrando uno por uno? o usando un timer. PD: Gracias por responder.

Comment: Échale un ojo a esto. http://alltutorial.in/android-image-slider-example/

Comment: Gracias por el ejemplo.